# Hub Control Not Working in Windows 10

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10

Hub control isn't working on UAP Appilcation in Visual Studio 2015 CTP.Here is My Code

```
<Hub>
        <HubSection Header="HubSection 0">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
        <HubSection Header="HubSection 1">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
```

There is a message on Designer Window :

> An Unhandled Exception Has Occurred
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException    [148] Designer process
>   terminated unexpectedly!

Comment: Don't worry about this, In my apps I have dozens of designer failures

Comment: This works when you run the app though right?  Could be an interim tools issue for the design/editor surface.